# Compilation of live555 library for iOS simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, i386, live555

I've compiled live555 library with

```
./genMakefiles iphoneos 
make
```

for iOS device, but I can't compile that for iOS simulator. 
Is anybody has any ideas how to do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you compile for iphoneos you are compiling the library for an arm processor. When running the iOS simulator you are running it on an intel x86 processor so it will produce errors along the lines of "symbols not found for i386/x86_64"

If you want to run it on the simulator then try running "./genMakefiles macosx"

If you know how to then you can specify which versions of the generated library files to link depending on what you're building for. Namely that it will link to the .a files if running on an ios device, or it will link the .dylib files when running on simulator

I hope that helps